# Joining same table multiples times (Query Performance Issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a certain feature which joins the same table multiple times to achieve the required result.. but it has some serious performance issues and I would like to improve it if possible, I'm open for any advises

```
SELECT @Param1 = magic1.ID ,
       @Param2 = magic2.ID ,
       @Param3 = magic3.ID ,
       @Param4 = magic4.ID ,
       @Param5 = magic5.ID ,
       @Param6 = magic6.ID ,
       @Param7 = magic7.ID ,
       @Param8 = magic8.ID ,
       @Param9 = magic9.ID ,
       @Param10 = magic10.ID,
       @ParamNum = items0.MagParamNum,
       @ID64 = items0.ID64
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory AS invent0
INNER JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Items AS items0 ON invent0.ItemID = items0.ID64 AND (invent0.Slot = 13)
INNER JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon AS ref0 ON items0.RefItemID = ref0.ID
INNER JOIN SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char AS chart ON invent0.CharID = chart.CharID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic1 ON (items0.MagParam1 & 2147483647) = magic1.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic2 ON (items0.MagParam2 & 2147483647) = magic2.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic3 ON (items0.MagParam3 & 2147483647) = magic3.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic4 ON (items0.MagParam4 & 2147483647) = magic4.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic5 ON (items0.MagParam5 & 2147483647) = magic5.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic6 ON (items0.MagParam6 & 2147483647) = magic6.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic7 ON (items0.MagParam7 & 2147483647) = magic7.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic8 ON (items0.MagParam8 & 2147483647) = magic8.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic9 ON (items0.MagParam9 & 2147483647) = magic9.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic10 ON (items0.MagParam10 & 2147483647) = magic10.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic11 ON (items0.MagParam11 & 2147483647) = magic11.ID
LEFT JOIN _RefMagicOptNew AS magic12 ON (items0.MagParam12 & 2147483647) = magic12.ID
WHERE chart.CharID = @CharID
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bad table design. Why all those MagParam columns?

Comment: It's used to define blues for an item, each magparam contains a blue(ingame stuff)

Comment: Why you need the "& 2147483647" part though... If you cannot remove it, you can try to add another 12 columns with the "items0.MagParam1 & 2147483647"  to "items0.MagParam12 & 2147483647" as values, and index them. Because i don't think your joins use any indexes

Comment: why do you need to join with _RefMagicOptNew when it looks like you need the ID from that table...Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't @Param1 = items0.MagParam1 & 2147483647 do the same thing?

Comment: What is datatype of MagParam1 (etc)? Some very big integer? Seems like you are storing two values inside one field and separating them out using `&`.